# Angularjs ui-grid filter cancel event

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

Hi I am using angular ui grid, I have filter and grouping in the grid
I am expanding by default all rows using following

```
$scope.expandAll = function(){
    $scope.gridApi.treeBase.expandAllRows();
  };

 $timeout(function() {
    $scope.expandAll();
}, 500);
```

[image]

now if user filter on any column which is not available in data

[image]

And then remove or cancel, It does not expand automatically

[image]

It shows like above

I need all rows to expand automatically when user clear or cancel filter data

I found there is an event **filterChanged**, but I don't know how to use that

I am using following plunkr for testing

http://plnkr.co/edit/hhIW9R9aX1JlFe4nodJQ?p=preview

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your onRegisterApi method to the following

```
onRegisterApi: function( gridApi ) {
  $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
  $scope.gridApi.core.on.filterChanged($scope, function() {        
    var grid = this.grid;
    var isfilterclear = true;
    angular.forEach(grid.columns, function( col ) {
      if(col.filters[0].term){
        isfilterclear = false;
      }
    });
    if(isfilterclear) {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.expandAll();
        },500);
    }
  });
}
```

see plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/1FWDIe?p=preview

Comment: I just end up doing     $timeout(function() {$scope.expandAll();},500); in my filterChanged function